# Sorteio de números com exceção

Tags: c, random

Como faço pra sortear uma quantidade `n` de números na linguagem C em que eu possa excluir a possibilidade de sortear um determinado número do meu intervalo dada uma determinada condição?

Exemplificando em código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
     int i,;
     int x[8];

     printf("Gerando 10 valores aleatorios:\n\n");
     for(i=0;i<8;i++){
        scanf("%d", &x[i]);
        if(x[i]==3){
                x[i] = rand()% 8 ("com exceção do i");
            }
        }
     }

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: O que você vai fazer com esses números? Colocá-los em um array? Ou vai gerá-los dentro de um `for` ou `while` e consumí-los durante a iteração sem precisar armazená-los para usar depois?

Comment: @VictorStafusa eu tenho um vetor de 8 posições, e quero que o programa faça o sorteio de 0 a 8. E vai ter uma condição que vai excluir determinado numero desse sorteio. Exemplo: if (contador==0){ nao coloque 3 no sorteio}. Tipo isso.

Comment: Edite a pergunta para torná-la mais clara. Não entendi direito. O que há nesse vetor? Você quer preencher 8 números aleatórios de 0 a 8 no vetor, escluindo um determinado número? Ou você quer escolher uma posição do vetor por algum motivo? Ou você quer apenas embaralhar o vetor?

Comment: @VictorStafusa editei a pergunta.

Comment: Ou seja, se o usuário digitar 3 é para colocar um número aleatório de 0 a 7 no array. Caso contrário é para colocar o número que o usuário digitar?

Comment: É exatamente isso, quando ele digitar 3  na posição 5 do vetor, o programa tem que substituir  por um numero aleatório que não seja 5.

Comment: Obrigado pela a ajuda a todos!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seguindo o mesmo raciocínio do colega Maniero, sugiro que repita a amostragem ate obter um valor valido. Ver o código abaixo.
Nota: deve-se usar `srand` para inicializar a amostragem de forma a obter valores diferentes sempre que se executa o programa.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    int x[8];

    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("Gerando 10 valores aleatorios:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &x[i]);
        if (x[i] == 3) {
            int sorteado = rand() % 8;
            while (sorteado == i){
                printf("recusado: %d ",sorteado);
                sorteado = rand() % 8;
            }
            printf("sorteado = %d \n",sorteado);    
            x[i] = sorteado;
        }
        printf("[%d] = %d\n", i, x[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Precisa ficar sorteando o número até não sair um que não te interessa. Existem outras soluções, mas para um casos simples assim não tem porque complicar. Seria isso:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int x[8];
    printf("Gerando 10 valores aleatorios:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &x[i]);
        if (x[i] == 3) {
            int sorteado = -1;
            while ((sorteado = rand() % 8) != i); //repete até achar um valor aceitável
            x[i] = sorteado;
        } else {
            x[i] = rand() % 8;
        }
        printf("[%d] = %d\n", i, x[i]);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/3fT8iJ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/gzpnpbpz-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Math/RandomExcept.c).